# Show data from 2 tables that one tables has more than 1 same datas

Tags: php, mysql

I Have doing normalization in my table :

from : `tb_1`

```
===================================
| id | doc_name | title  | author |
===================================
| 1  | doc1     | title1 | author1|
|    |          |        | author2|
| 2  | doc2     | title2 | author3|
|    |          |        | author4|
===================================
```

become :

```
tb_a                            tb_b
=======================       =========================
|id_a|doc_name| title |       |id_b| doc_name| author |
=======================       =========================
| 1  | doc1   | title1|       |  1 | title1  |author1 |
| 2  | doc2   | title2|       |  2 | title1  |author2 |
=======================       |  3 | title2  |author3 |
                              |  4 | title2  |author2 |
                              =========================
```

I wanna show the result like :

`doc1 title1 author1 author2`

`doc2 title2 author3 author4`

here's the code :

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT tb_a.doc_name, tb_a.title,
                              tb_b.doc_name, tb_b.author
                       FROM tb_a
                       JOIN  tb_b ON tb_a.doc_name = tb_b.doc_name ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $doc     = $row['doc_name'];
   $title   = $row['title'];
   $author  = $row['author'];

   echo $doc; echo $title ; echo $author;
}
```

But the result is :
`doc1 title1 author1` `doc1 title1 author2`
`doc2 title2 author3` `doc2 title2 author4`

please help me, thanks you very much :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a side suggestion: `tb_b` should not contain a `doc_name` column, since that's redundant with `tb_a`. That column should be replaced with `doc_id`, which contains the `id_a` column from the corresponding row in `tb_a`.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying pivot your table.  Not sure how you want your output, but you could use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) since you're using mysql.

Would look something like

```
   SELECT tb1.doc, tb1.title, group_concat(tb2.author)
     FROM tb1
     JOIN tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id
 GROUP BY tb1.doc, tb1.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tb_a.doc_name, tb_a.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tb_b.author) authors
FROM tb_a
JOIN tb_b ON tb_a.title = tb_b.doc_name
GROUP BY tb_a.doc_name, tb_a.title
```